# Alias Column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two simple columns: `datetime PayDate` and `int Amount`
I tried to write a query that separate count of `Amount` per day but it doesnt work.

```
SELECT YEAR(PayDate) + '/' + MONTH(PayDate) + '/' + DAY(PayDate) as a,
COUNT(Amount) as b
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY a,b
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL? Did you tag both by accident, to cast a wider net, or ...?

Comment: Hi, I tag both because syntax is same.

Comment: that's presumptuous; it might not be. For example my answer has code that will work on SQL Server but not on MySQL. If you are trying to get generic code that is compatible with both platforms, you should state so explicitly instead of forcing people to make assumptions from your tags. Also realize that it is not always going to be possible.

Comment: Im sorry, it was not intentional. I just thought this code is too simple and can use in both `sql-server` and `mysql`. I promise to dont do that again. Also now Im glad because I understood how to solve this problem in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you bothering with all this messy string concatenation? Format on the client if you want a specific output. Use base types instead of strings where possible.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, PayDate) AS a, COUNT(Amount) AS b
FROM dbo.TABLE1
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, PayDate);
```

If you have a *justified* complex expression, the easiest way to avoid repeating it is to use a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT a, COUNT(b) FROM
(SELECT CONVERT(DATE, PayDate) AS a, Amount AS b FROM dbo.TABLE1) AS x
GROUP BY a;

-- or

WITH x(a,b) AS
(SELECT CONVERT(DATE, PayDate), Amount FROM dbo.TABLE1)
SELECT a, COUNT(b) FROM x
GROUP BY a;
```

(I have no idea why you are grouping by both a and b in your question.)

Comment: And what if I want to do that in `mysql`? is it different?

Comment: @masoud yes, probably. I don't work with MySQL, but this is the problem you face when you ask a two-pronged question, not all of the answers will be suitable to your entire problem.

Answer (score 3):

At least in SQL Server, you cannot use the *alias* in the GROUP BY statement.  You have to repeat the statement.

Sad, but true.

```
SELECT YEAR(PayDate) + '/' + MONTH(PayDate) + '/' + DAY(PayDate) as a,
COUNT(Amount) as b
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY YEAR(PayDate) + '/' + MONTH(PayDate) + '/' + DAY(PayDate),COUNT(Amount)
```

Comment: `COUNT(Amount)` doesn't make sense in the `GROUP BY` list.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '/' to data type int.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the *alias* in the `GROUP BY` statement. And no need to use `GROUP BY Count(Amount)`

```
SELECT YEAR(PayDate) + '/' + MONTH(PayDate) + '/' + DAY(PayDate) as a,
COUNT(Amount) as b
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY YEAR(PayDate) + '/' + MONTH(PayDate) + '/' + DAY(PayDate)
```

Or other way to do this in SQL Server:

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(20),PayDate,111) as a,
COUNT(Amount) as b
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY Convert(varchar(20),PayDate,111)
```

See [Cast and Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL, you can also get the date of a datetime column simply buy using. I don;t know why you would group by alias b in this case. You probably also want to order by the date value in most cases.

```
SELECT DATE(PayDate) as a, COUNT(Amount) as b
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY a
ORDER BY a
```